# Accumulation point and open set

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $S$ is open then any point of $S$ is an accumulation point.

**Definition $1$:**
A set $S$ is open if any element $s$ in $S$ has a neighborhood $(s-h,s+h)$ entirely included in $S$.

**Definition $2$:** An element $y$ is an accumulation point for a set $S$ if any neighborhood of $y$ contains at least one element of $S$ that is not $y$.

Comment: Remark: The claim is not true for general topological spaces instead of $\mathbb R$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Do you have a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s \in S$. Since $S$ is an open set by hypothesis, then there exists a neighborhood $(s - h, s + h)$ entirely included in $S$ (from Def. $1$). Since

$$s - h < s < \frac{s + s + h}{2} < s + h \iff s - h < s < s + \frac h2 < s + h$$

we have that the point $s + \frac h2$ is included in $S$ and as $s + \frac h2 \neq s$, necessarily $s$ is an accumulation point (from Def. $2$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $s \in S$ be arbitrary. Since $S$ is open, then we can find an open ball $B(s, \epsilon) \subset S$. Since $s$ is arbitrary, we know that every point of $S$ has a neighborhood (open ball) that contains at least one point of $S$. Hence, $s$ is an accumulation point.

Comment: How do you know that point in B is not s?

Comment: Try $s+\frac12\epsilon$.

Comment: how do you know s+ϵ/2 is a point of the Set

Comment: 1) intro to real analysis 2) I do not know actually... but given the course level.. I would say it is just R?

Comment: I have little idea of the concept of "metric"... but ok lol